# How do I print a hash structure in Perl?

Tags: perl, hash

Examples:

```
%hash = (2010 => 21, 2009=> 9);

$hash = {
    a => {
        0 => {test => 1},
        1 => {test => 2},
        2 => {test => 3},
        3 => {test => 4},
    },
};
```

How do I print the hash?

Comment: Also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363142/how-to-iterate-through-hash

Comment: See the Perl Data Structures Cookbook - perldoc perldsc on the command line or at http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html

Answer (score 20):

Do you want to print the entire hash, or specific key, value pairs? And what is your desired result? IF it's just for debugging purposes, you can do something like:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper %hash; # or \%hash to encapsulate it as a single hashref entity;
```

You can use the `each` function if you don't care about ordering:

```
while ( my($key, $value) = each %hash ) {
    print "$key = $value\n";
}
```

Or the `for` / `foreach` construct if you want to sort it:

```
for my $key ( sort keys %hash ) {
    print "$key = $hash{$key}\n";
}
```

Or if you want only certain values, you can use a hash slice, e.g.:

```
print "@hash{qw{2009 2010}}\n";
```

etc, etc. There is always more than one way to do it, though it helps to know what you're frying to do first :)

Comment: I may be wrong but I believe the OP hash problems with syntax to access items or even hash using hash references, not with iterators on hashes. Notice than in his second exemple his variable is a scalar $hash, not a hash.

Comment: @kriss: The original question asked how to print a hash, it would appear the OP has edited the question with a further example. The first example of using Data::Dumper will still handle that correctly.

Comment: @Duncan: Data::Dumper works everywhere. On the other hand there is more than printing data ;-)

Comment: @kriss: There is more to printing a hash than printing data? The question is "How do I print a hash structure in Perl?" :)

Answer (score 2):

```
  while( my( $key, $value ) = each( %hash ) ) {
         ...
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of

```
%hash = { 2010=> 21, 2009=> 9 }
```

you should write

```
%hash = ( 2010=> 21, 2009=> 9 );
```

with the curly braces you get a REFERENCE to an anonymous hash,
which is then stored as the first key of you %hash.

Comment: and worse, it's stored in stringified form!

Comment: yes, but in his **second** exemple the OP wrote : $h = { some content }; and **that** may be legitimate (say to pass a hash reference to a sub). (Even if you are probably right and it is a newbie mistake).

Answer (score 2):

Syntax to access inner cells for your second example is like:

```
print $hash->{"a"}{0}{"test"}
```

That will give you 1 in your example.

If you want to iterate on it, you can do it as follows (print lines are for illustration purposes):

```
my $hash = {"a"=>{ 0=>{"test"=>1}, 1=>{"test"=>2}, 2=>{"test"=>3}, 3=>{"test"=>4} } };
print "Direct access to item : ".$hash->{"a"}{1}{"test"}."\n";

foreach my $k1 (keys(%$hash)) {
    print "keys of level 1: $k1\n";
    foreach my $k2 (keys(%{$hash->{$k1}})) {
        print "keys of level 2: $k2\n";
        print "values: ".$hash->{$k1}{$k2}{"test"}."\n"
     }
}
```

Notice that things are a bit more tricky than necessary because the external $hash is a scalar reference to an anonymous hash. It would be simpler if it was a hash (i.e., like in `my %hash = (1, 2); print $hash{1};`).

(**TIMTOWTDI**: there is obviously more than one way to do it; I believe the above example is the simplest for me, but not the most efficient; using `each` instead of `keys` for iterating would avoid one unnecessary hash lookup).

Comment: Most programmers do not write double sigils and repeated arrows. This notation is much more readable: `$hash->{'a'}{0}{'test'}`

Comment: @daxim: yes, i tried to make it more explicit for beginner but I probably failed on this one. I will change it.

Comment: Recursion is probably too advanced at this stage?

Comment: @Duncan: probably, but I don't really see where you want to put recursion in that question ? Some example on how to use hashes to make trees or graphs ?

Answer (score 1):

you can try with this,

```
while(my ($key,$val)=each %HASH){
print $key," = ",$val,"\n";
while(my ($kkey,$vval)=each %{$HASH{$key}}){
print "   ",$kkey," = ",$vval,"\n";
}
}
```

Comment: Did you try it? What is the result of the first print: `print $key," = ",$val,"\n";`

Answer (score 0):

use `keys , values` function

```
@keys = keys %hash ; 

@values = values %hash
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
foreach $key (keys %hash)
{
  print "key is : $key, value is : $hash{$key}\n";
}
```

cheers

Comment: Thanks for reply if my hash is like this 

$hash = {'a'=>{
      0=>{'test'=>'1'},
      1=>{'test'=>'2'},
      2=>{'test'=>'3'},
      3=>{'test'=>'4'}
     }
    };
Then what I will do

Answer (score 0):

```
printf ("%s = %s\n", $_, $hash {$_}) foreach (keys (%hash));
```

Answer (score 0):

The function printStruct below works using recursion and can print hashes of arrays, arrays of hashes or any mixture thereof to any depth. You call it with a reference to your structure, and a name of the structure in a string. The last input $pre is only used during the recursion to tell the initial entry into the recursive function. Just leave it blank when you call the function.

```
%hash = (2010 => 21, 2009=> 9);
printStruct(\%hash,"\%hash");

$hash = {
    a => {
        0 => {test => 1},
        1 => {test => 2},
        2 => {test => 3},
        3 => {test => 4},
    },
};
$hash->{b}=[1..5];
printStruct($hash,"\$hash");
my @array=[apple,banana,orange,$hash];
printStruct(\@array,"\@array");

sub printStruct {
    my ($struct,$structName,$pre)=@_;
    print "-----------------\n" unless (defined($pre));
    if (!ref($struct)){ # $struct is a scalar.
    print "$structName=$struct\n";
    } elsif (ref($struct) eq "ARRAY") { # Struct is an array reference
    return ("ARRAY(".scalar(@$struct).")") if (@$struct>100);
    for(my$i=0;$i<@$struct;$i++) {
        if (ref($struct->[$i]) eq "HASH") {
        printStruct($struct->[$i],$structName."->[$i]",$pre." ");
        } elsif (ref($struct->[$i]) eq "ARRAY") { # contents of struct is array ref
        print "$structName->"."[$i]=()\n" if (@{$struct->[$i]}==0);
        my $string = printStruct($struct->[$i],$structName."->[$i]",$pre." ");
        print "$structName->"."[$i]=$string\n" if ($string);
        } else { # contents of struct is a scalar, just print it.
        print "$structName->"."[$i]=$struct->[$i]\n";
        }
    }
    return();
    } else { # $struct is a hash reference or a scalar
    foreach (sort keys %{$struct}) {
        if (ref($struct->{$_}) eq "HASH") {
        printStruct($struct->{$_},$structName."->{$_}",$pre." ");
        } elsif (ref($struct->{$_}) eq "ARRAY") { # contents of struct is array ref
        my $string = printStruct($struct->{$_},$structName."->{$_}",$pre." ");
        print "$structName->"."{$_}=$string\n" if ($string);
        } else { # contents of struct is a scalar, just print it.
        print "$structName->"."{$_}=$struct->{$_}\n";
        }
    }
    return();
    } 
    print "------------------\n" unless (defined($pre));
    return();
}
```

Result:

```
-----------------
%hash->{2009}=9
%hash->{2010}=21
-----------------
$hash->{a}->{0}->{test}=1
$hash->{a}->{1}->{test}=2
$hash->{a}->{2}->{test}=3
$hash->{a}->{3}->{test}=4
$hash->{b}->[0]=1
$hash->{b}->[1]=2
$hash->{b}->[2]=3
$hash->{b}->[3]=4
$hash->{b}->[4]=5
-----------------
@array->[0]->[0]=apple
@array->[0]->[1]=banana
@array->[0]->[2]=orange
@array->[0]->[3]->{a}->{0}->{test}=1
@array->[0]->[3]->{a}->{1}->{test}=2
@array->[0]->[3]->{a}->{2}->{test}=3
@array->[0]->[3]->{a}->{3}->{test}=4
@array->[0]->[3]->{b}->[0]=1
@array->[0]->[3]->{b}->[1]=2
@array->[0]->[3]->{b}->[2]=3
@array->[0]->[3]->{b}->[3]=4
@array->[0]->[3]->{b}->[4]=5
```

This function helped in a lot of programming and debugging of complex structures. I hope you guys find it as useful.